How to choose a proper structure (to be more precise: an output layer) for an Optical Character Recognition model?
My question might be silly, but I don't understand. I have pictures with 8 symbols on each one. Number of classes (length of the alphabet) is equal to 25. I need an LSTM model to predict those symbols. I am going to use CTCLoss, so the input to the loss function should be (Input_length, batch_size, number of classes), i.e. in my case (8, batch_size, 25).
Should I use nn.Linear(2 * rnn_hidden, num_symbols * num_classes) as an output layer of the model? Or is it better to have nn.Linear(2 * rnn_hidden, num_classes) as an output layer and just divide image to 8 parts with each symbol separately and apply the model to each one? Or maybe there are other methods?
I would be incredibly grateful for your help!
Currently I am trying this one: nn.Linear(2 * rnn_hidden, num_symbols * num_classes), but I am not sure it is a proper option.

Welcome to [so]. I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.  Split your task into smaller ones and start working on them. And ask particular questions related to particular issues you encounter. Here's how: how-to-ask
